# What's the point of annotating an argument as np.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

Say I have the following file `t2.py`:

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import Dict, Any

def func(arr: np.ndarray):
    arr.to_json()
    arr.to_jason()

class MyClass:
    def to_json(self) -> Dict[str, Any]: ...

def my_func(arr: MyClass):
    arr.to_json()
    arr.to_jason()
```

If I run `mypy` I get

```
$ mypy t2.py --ignore-missing-imports
t2.py:13: error: "MyClass" has no attribute "to_jason"; maybe "to_json"?
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

So, in `func2`, when I annotated `arr` as `MyClass` and then called a non-existent method on it, `mypy` found the error. But the same didn't happen in `func` when I called non-existent methods on `arr` annotated as `np.ndarray`.

Indeed, if I use `reveal_type`, then in `func` I see that it is of type `Any`.

*However*, I see loads of people annotate variables as `np.ndarray` in their code. Why do people do this? Is it just for readability, or can it help mypy actually find any bugs?

Comment: This is probably because the numpy internals are written in C. So while mypy can read python classes for member functions, it has a hard time dealing with C libraries.

Comment: I don't think it's that. If I type it as `arr: pd.Series` then `mypy` also finds no error and the revealed type is `Any`, but in pandas the `Series` class is defined in Python

Comment: Consider that mypy cannot detect the error *yet*. Once the scientific libraries ship with proper annotations, mypy (and other type checkers) will be able to inspect their usage. That means code that is properly annotated already currently provides documentation, and will provide type safety in the future without requiring people to re-visit it.

Comment: Please be aware that "why do people do X" is practically asking for opinion, which is off-topic. Even when rewording the question, it is probably too broad – there are *loads* of reason to annotate things even when they are not checked, such as for documentation or simply not knowing that the type is not properly checked.

Comment: If you create a list in your code, and try and pass that to your function expecting an ndarray, will mypy fail on that? If so, then it at least helps you keep your own code consistent while you wait for numpy to ship with type annotations of its own.